# Cannot install Spotify on Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, 18.04, spotify

I'm trying to install Spotify on my Lubuntu following this guide: https://www.spotify.com/ar/download/linux/.

But neither of the methods work.

With *snap* I get on console `error: snap "spotify" not found`.

And with the deb package I get

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 spotify-client : Depends: libcurl3 but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: libavcodec-ffmpeg56 but it is not installable or
                              libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 but it is not installable or
                              libavcodec54 but it is not installable or
                              libavcodec-extra-54 but it is not installable
                  Recommends: libavformat-ffmpeg56 but it is not installable or
                              libavformat54 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do to install Spotify in Lubuntu 18.04? I was able to install it with *snap* on Kubuntu 18.04 about a month ago.

Comment: Before installing Spotify, fix your apt problem! That's much more important.

Answer (score 0):

Did you intall the restricted extra for lubuntu? the missing depenencies may be codecs.

Try this first then reinstall Spotify

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-restricted-addons
```